# Django MultipleChoiceField don't update initual data in Form overload

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to load default values for a MultipleChoiceField in a Form overload.

So if I give the initial variable inside the MultipleChoiceField it works:

```
class UserPreferences(forms.Form):
    my_form = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices = MY_CHOICES,
        initial = MY_INITIAL_DICT)
```

But if I try to get initial values from the database related to a user and update initial as follows, my_form initial variable doesn't change and stays empty:

```
class UserPreferences(forms.Form):
    my_form = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices = MY_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, user):
        initial = make_my_dict_from( MyModel.objects.filter(user=user) )

        super(UserPreferences, self).__init__(initial, empty_permitted)
```

If I do this with a simple ChoiceField it works, but not with MultipleChoiceField.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
super(UserPreferences, self).__init__(initial=initial)
```

You need to use keyword arguments like this. Python does not look at your variable names, and uses the right slots.

Where does "empty_permitted" come from? Your example does use, but not define this variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reproduce well my real exemple in __init__ I have much more parameters. Sure, initial=initual and so on for the rest of the parameters is a better and cleaner practice, but that wasn't my problem. Django has a special behariour with MultipleChoiceFields. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have used MultipleChoiceFields, and AFAIK there is no special behaviour.